# How to secure Superset '/login/' endpoint

Tags: rest, flask, apache-superset, websecurity, flask-appbuilder

Recently I integrated superset with my web application so that when an user who is authenticated by my web application can enter superset and view/edit/create dashboards based on their role just by clicking the link no need to even login. For doing this I had to bypass the login for which I referred [this](https://sairamkrish.medium.com/apache-superset-custom-authentication-and-integrate-with-other-micro-services-8217956273c1) article.

**Custom SecurityManager I used to bypass login**

```
class CustomAuthDBView(AuthDBView):

    @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self):
        redirect_url = self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index
        user_name = request.args.get('username')
        user_role = request.args.get('role')
        if user_name is not None:
            user = self.appbuilder.sm.find_user(username=user_name)
            if not user:
                role = self.appbuilder.sm.find_role(user_role)
                user = self.appbuilder.sm.add_user(user_name, user_name, 'last_name', user_name + "@domain.com", role, password = "password")
            if user:
                login_user(user, remember=False)
                return redirect(redirect_url)

        else:
            print('Unable to auto login', 'warning')
            return super(CustomAuthDBView,self).login()

class CustomSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authdbview = CustomAuthDBView
    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(CustomSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
```

So according to above code using url  `http://localhost:8088/login?username=John` will login the user John internally or if user John does not exist account is created with some role which is based on the role of user in my web application

Now the problem is anyone who can guess this url   `http://localhost:8088/login?username=USER_NAME` can create their account in superset, so how to protect or secure this `'/login'` endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API so that you dont expose request details over the URL.

```
from flask_appbuilder.api import BaseApi, expose
from . import appbuilder

    class LoginApi(BaseApi):

    resource_name = "login"
    
    @expose('/loginapi/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    #@has_access
    
    def loginapi(self):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.json['username']
            password = request.json['password']



appbuilder.add_api(LoginApi)
```